# icon and subject of lesson

Tags: icon

Please help me create the three red arrows below because I tried to create icons like those icons but could not possibly not need the script that needed its icon! Thank you! [image]

Comment: The uppermost symbol looks like `\faFolderOpen` from the `fontawesome` package, the lowest one like `\faPencilSquare` and the ones in the middle `\faCheckSquareO` all from that package.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend the [`fontawesome`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) package, which contains a large collection of web-related symbols (edited thanks to @marmot’s comment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
Open Folder: \faFolderOpen

Check box: \faCheckSquareO

Edit: \faEdit

Pencil in a square: \faPencilSquare

\textbf{Bonus round}

Light bulb: \faLightbulbO

Bookmark: \faBookmark
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]